# Infinite local notifications for alarm app

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm currently writing an alarm application, which should be sending infinite local notifications if app is terminated. Similar logic is implemented in [Alarmy app](https://apps.apple.com/am/app/alarmy-alarm-clock-sleep/id1163786766).

Local push notifications count is restricted to 64, which means we probably should use `repeating` option like this.

```
func setNotification(date: Date, ringtoneName: String, repeatWeekdays: [Int], snoozeEnabled: Bool, onSnooze: Bool, uuid: String, sleepMoreMinit: Int) {
    let datesForNotification = getNotificationDates(baseDate: date, onWeekdaysForNotify: repeatWeekdays)
    
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = "Alarm"
    notificationContent.body = "Wake Up"
    for date in datesForNotification {
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute, .second], from: date)
        for i in 0..<60 {
            dateComponents.second = (dateComponents.second ?? 0) + 1
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(date)",
                                                content: notificationContent,
                                                trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { _ in }
        }
    }
}
```

But the thing is local notifications can be repeated only once per minute, so I don't understand how Alarmy sends infinite notifications each second.
Is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Interesting that the two existing reviews of the app complained about battery drainage, maybe you don't want a solution like Alarmy has.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately this is what I'm requested to do, and struggling to find a solution for weeks now :(